Different types with same underlying implementation
I want to create distinct types A, B, and C. All these three types share the same functionality (their common functionalities have the same implementation), but these three need to be different types so that there are no implicit conversions anywhere.
So far I have thought of the following, but all are either bad or don't satisfy my use case.

Putting the common functionality in the base class, and have these 3 inherit from them. But then all these three are essentially the same type.

Copy the implementation 3 times so that A, B, and C have the same class definition. But that's definitely a bad solution.

Because of the shared functionality, I thought of creating a template class. But the objects of this template class will all be same and will only differ on the templated type. And anyone can create a new type with the same typename and that would end up defeating the purpose.


template <typename T>
class TemplatedClass{
   public:
     TemplatedClass(T val) {.....}

};

using A = TemplatedClass<type1>;
using B = TemplatedClass<type2>;

using RogueType = TemplatedClass<type1>;;

// now A and RogueType are just aliases instead of being different types.


Create a macro class and use that to "copy" implementation, but I don't want to use macro because of the hassle they introduce in debugging.

Is there a design pattern that I can use to ensure that A, B, and C have the same templated implementation underneath, but still create different types.
I understand this can sound stupid, but this is unfortunately a weird use case that I am stuck with.
Thank you

Consider Boost strong typedef.

You're making too big a fuss about what you claim is "essentially the same type".   Either the common base class or a template option is viable.  A and B are distinct types (no conversions between them) even if they have a common base.   TemplateClass<type1> and TemplateClass<type2>, when type1 and type2 are different, are also distinct types (no conversions between them, unless you explicitly implement such conversions). It is not possible to prevent either using or typedef to create synonyms for any type, except in a context that doesn't have access to the name of the type.

"anyone can create a new type with the same typename": Anyone could inherit if you went with option one, and anyone could also copy the implementation if you went with option 2. If you document that TemplatedClass is internal (usually by putting it in a impl:: or detail:: namespace), this isn't a real problem

Um, "And anyone can create a new type with the same typename and that would end up defeating the purpose" - a using alias can be applied to any type that can be named.   If this is a deal breaker for you, you literally cannot use a type to solve your problem.

template<class D>
struct TemplatedClass {
  /* stuff */
};

struct A : TemplatedClass<A> {
  using TemplatedClass<A>::TemplatedClass;
};
struct B : TemplatedClass<B> {
  using TemplatedClass<B>::TemplatedClass;
};
struct C : TemplatedClass<C> {
  using TemplatedClass<C>::TemplatedClass;
};

A, B and C are identical classes with one-line bodies.
template<class T, template<class...>class B>
concept has_crtp_base = std::is_base_of<B<T>, T>::value;
  
template<class T>
concept is_bob = has_crtp_base<T, TemplatedClass>;

you can use these concepts to write template code that only consumes types like A, B and C.  Ie, suppose you wanted to write an operator<<:
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, is_bob auto const& b ) {
  // code that interacts with b knowing it is TemplatedClass based
  return os;
}

allowing you to write generic code that operates on all 3 of these types easily without having to be able to convert between them.
Someone creating a D variant incorrectly:
struct D : TemplatedClass<C> {
  using TemplatedClass<C>::TemplatedClass;
};

will fail the is_bob test, as D is not derived from TemplatedClass<D>.
(Here, I'm using bob as the name for the meta-type that all 3 of these types are kinds of).

This is nice, thank you. I have been thinking about going via the CRTP route, will try it out.

I suggest you use the base class method, but make the inheritance private. The relationship is then "implemented-in-terms-of" instead of "is-a".

A,B, and C have the common functionality implementation as member:
class CommonFunctionality{ ... };

class A
{
private:
  CommonFunctionality m_TheCommonImpl;
};

class B
{
private:
  CommonFunctionality m_TheCommonImpl;
};


Or... as a dirty way, copy the common implementation code using #include :
class A
{
#include "CommonCode"
};

class B
{
#include "CommonCode"
};

